# Como criar video através de uma sequencia de imagem?

Tags: java, android, vídeo

Quero criar um **vídeo** utilizando um **conjunto de imagens** do mesmo tipo e tamanho.

Pesquisei alguns exemplos mas não obtive sucesso na realização do algoritmo. Dos exemplos, o deste link foi o mais completo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337091/video-encode-from-sequence-of-images-from-java-android

Entretanto, a resposta não menciona todos pacotes `.jar` utilizados, pesquisei os que faltavam na internet mas não achei a versão correta.

Busco uma forma alternativa ou uma solução para este exemplo do link.

Answer (score 2):

Fala Cristian,

Você pode usar a função Animation do Android, por exemplo:

Crie um arquivo **animacao.xml**

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imagem1" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imagem2" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imagem3" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imagem4" android:duration="100"/>
</animation-list>
```

Depois você cria um ImageView no seu layout, exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/animacao"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Depois é só você instânciar no Java e chamar a animação, exemplo:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animacao);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animacao);

AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
animation.start();
```

Irá funcionar como se fosse um vídeo, resolveria seu caso?

Abraços.

Comment: Bem legal, mas preciso mesmo formar um vídeo.